# Should CSS be included in NPM component libraries or loaded manually?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have a React component which I make available as a NPM package. The package contains component-specific CSS styles.

What is the best practice regarding how these styles should be included? Should they be **part of the Webpack/Rollup bundle** (convenient for users) or should users be asked to **import/link the stylesheet manually** (better for overriding styles and possible to replace with own stylesheet)?

I've seen both approaches in popular libraries and am unsure which one to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends - If you expect your users would most likely override your styles, then it would be better to import the stylesheet manually. But if you are sure that your average user won't need to override your styles, then the styles can be a part of the bundle.